# OperationalError: could not connect to server: Operation timed out - when trying to change database from sqlite to postresql

Tags: amazon-web-services, postgresql, amazon-rds

I have upgraded my RDS amazon db instance (postgresql database ) from micro to small. Although it says that it is available on the amazon console, I keep getting the error `(psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection timed out`. everytime I access the db from my app.
when trying to access the server from my ubuntu machine with:

```
psql -h Ip -d db -U myuser
```

I get the same error:

```
psql: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
    Is the server running on host "IP" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

On the other hand, everything seems fine as well inside of PgAdmin4.

I am wondering if I just need to wait a bit longer to let things initialize. By the way, I am working on a django project, are there some settings that I need to take care off after such an upgrate? Has someone had the same problem?

here is postgres error log:

```
2020-08-07 10:00:16 UTC::@:[13371]:LOG: checkpoint starting: time
2020-08-07 10:00:16 UTC::@:[13371]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 1 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.101 s, sync=0.005 s, total=0.132 s; sync files=1, longest=0.005 s, average=0.005 s; distance=65536 kB, estimate=65537 kB
2020-08-07 10:05:16 UTC::@:[13371]:LOG: checkpoint starting: time
2020-08-07 10:05:16 UTC::@:[13371]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 1 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.101 s, sync=0.005 s, total=0.136 s; sync files=1, longest=0.005 s, average=0.005 s; distance=65536 kB, estimate=65537 kB
2020-08-07 10:10:16 UTC::@:[13371]:LOG: checkpoint starting: time
2020-08-07 10:10:16 UTC::@:[13371]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 1 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.101 s, sync=0.005 s, total=0.135 s; sync files=1, longest=0.005 s, average=0.005 s; distance=65534 kB, estimate=65537 kB
2020-08-07 10:12:03 UTC::@:[13368]:LOG: received fast shutdown request
2020-08-07 10:12:03 UTC::@:[13368]:LOG: aborting any active transactions
2020-08-07 10:12:03 UTC::@:[13368]:LOG: background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 13377) exited with exit code 1
2020-08-07 10:12:03 UTC::@:[13371]:LOG: shutting down
2020-08-07 10:12:03 UTC::@:[13371]:LOG: checkpoint starting: shutdown immediate
2020-08-07 10:12:03 UTC::@:[13371]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 1 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.000 s, sync=0.007 s, total=0.037 s; sync files=1, longest=0.007 s, average=0.007 s; distance=65535 kB, estimate=65537 kB
2020-08-07 10:12:03 UTC::@:[13368]:LOG: database system is shut down
2020-08-07 10:12:06 UTC::@:[28963]:LOG: database system was shut down at 2020-08-07 10:12:03 UTC
2020-08-07 10:12:06 UTC::@:[28961]:LOG: database system is ready to accept connections
2020-08-07 10:17:06 UTC::@:[28964]:LOG: checkpoint starting: time
2020-08-07 10:17:07 UTC::@:[28964]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 3 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.881 s, sync=0.006 s, total=0.921 s; sync files=3, longest=0.006 s, average=0.002 s; distance=16 kB, estimate=16 kB
2020-08-07 10:22:06 UTC::@:[28964]:LOG: checkpoint starting: time
2020-08-07 10:22:06 UTC::@:[28964]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 1 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.678 s, sync=0.006 s, total=0.712 s; sync files=1, longest=0.006 s, average=0.006 s; distance=65521 kB, estimate=65521 kB
2020-08-07 10:27:06 UTC::@:[28964]:LOG: checkpoint starting: time
2020-08-07 10:27:07 UTC::@:[28964]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 1 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.693 s, sync=0.006 s, total=0.727 s; sync files=1, longest=0.006 s, average=0.006 s; distance=65536 kB, estimate=65536 kB
2020-08-07 10:32:06 UTC::@:[28964]:LOG: checkpoint starting: time
2020-08-07 10:32:06 UTC::@:[28964]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 1 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.101 s, sync=0.005 s, total=0.131 s; sync files=1, longest=0.005 s, average=0.005 s; distance=65536 kB, estimate=65536 kB
2020-08-07 10:37:06 UTC::@:[28964]:LOG: checkpoint starting: time
2020-08-07 10:37:06 UTC::@:[28964]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 1 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.101 s, sync=0.005 s, total=0.131 s; sync files=1, longest=0.005 s, average=0.005 s; distance=65535 kB, estimate=65536 kB
2020-08-07 10:42:06 UTC::@:[28964]:LOG: checkpoint starting: time
2020-08-07 10:42:06 UTC::@:[28964]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 1 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.101 s, sync=0.005 s, total=0.132 s; sync files=1, longest=0.005 s, average=0.005 s; distance=65536 kB, estimate=65536 kB
2020-08-07 10:47:06 UTC::@:[28964]:LOG: checkpoint starting: time
2020-08-07 10:47:06 UTC::@:[28964]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 1 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.101 s, sync=0.005 s, total=0.135 s; sync files=1, longest=0.005 s, average=0.005 s; distance=65536 kB, estimate=65536 kB
2020-08-07 10:52:06 UTC::@:[28964]:LOG: checkpoint starting: time
2020-08-07 10:52:07 UTC::@:[28964]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 1 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.101 s, sync=0.006 s, total=0.133 s; sync files=1, longest=0.006 s, average=0.006 s; distance=65535 kB, estimate=65536 kB
2020-08-07 10:57:06 UTC::@:[28964]:LOG: checkpoint starting: time
2020-08-07 10:57:06 UTC::@:[28964]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 1 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.101 s, sync=0.005 s, total=0.137 s; sync files=1, longest=0.005 s, average=0.005 s; distance=65536 kB, estimate=65536 kB
----------------------- END OF LOG --
```

I tried testing the port on the server, rebooting my RDS instance nothing works, I have also uninstalled and re installed psycopg2 and sqlalchemy.

I can connect to the db from the command line. I tested the port with nmap, giving the following result:

```
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
5432/tcp filtered postgresql
```

I am still super confused and the app not working for the past 10 hours! I cannot find out where this is coming from, I would love some help on this issue, I start to get pressured at work. thank you

UPDATE: I have just noticed that in the aws console in `database/mydb/configurations/parameters group`, it says `default.postgres11 (in-sync)`. Could that be the cause of the sudden issue after the upgrade? I don't remember saying in-sync before, I wonder how long it is going to last

Comment: A timeout usually points toward a firewall issue.

Comment: where could I start debugging?

Answer (score 2):

> psql: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
> Is the server running on **host "IP"** and accepting
> TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Are you really connecting to an **IP Address** rather to its **DNS name**? That could be the problem - when changing the RDS size the IP had changed. And in fact it can change from time to time unexpectedly.

Never use the IP directly (e.g. *172.31.x.x*), always use the DNS name like *myrds.xxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com*.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I wrote IP to not display the IP address of my rds instance. From what you are saying, I should rather write the amazon endpoint address? would that mean that I should also have it in my postgresql.conf file, as well as pg_hba.conf file?

Comment: Yes, use *myrds.xxx.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com* rather then the IP like *172.31.x.x*. The IP does change from time to time. The DNS name doesn’t.

Comment: thank you for your help, I am able to manually connect to the db from command and psql now. When the app try to access the db, it still output the same error, would you have a hint on where to look at to modify the outdated IP (knowing that django setting file is already good with the dns name?

Comment: Have you restarted Apache / Nginx? Django only reads the settings file on start.

Comment: yes nginx and supervisorctl are re loaded

Comment: Reboot the instance then. The IP may be cached somewhere else. Also check that it’s not in some other config file with `grep -r 172.31.x.x` or whatever the IP is.